# Making ogoneks with GREP style

Tags: typography, adobe-indesign

I followed [this solution](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2078/5489) to make Polish ogoneks in InDesign through GREP style BUT every time I use it, the negative tracking is also be applied to the space or next character which immediately follows it. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Who are you asking? What is an ogunek? What steps are you referring to?

Comment: There was an earlier question about "How to create a new glyph = letter + ogunek in Indesign" which showed step by step how to create these special letters that appear in the Polish and Lithuanian languages using a grep style. The steps mentioned worked like a charm BUT negative kerning is being applied to the character which immediately follows. I'm new to this site, so I wasn't sure how to pose this question in a way it would make sense or if there was a way to pose this question as another layer to this previous posting!

Comment: If you can reference the other question (via a link) that would certainly help clarify things.

Comment: the original sequence of steps was posted by Alan Gilbertson.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2078/5685

Comment: this is the link to which I refer—http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2078/5685

Comment: @Alan Gilbertson you are being paged!

Answer (score 2):

Ideally there would be a regular expression that would say something like "if e is followed by ogonek, then style e", because that would only apply the negative tracking to the initial letter. I wasn't able to figure that out, though, so here's a workaround:

Create another character style. You already have one that has your negative tracking; create another one that has a tracking of 0. Apply the negative tracking style to "e˛" or whatever your range of characters is, and then apply the tracking style of 0 to just the ogonek.

[image: GREP Styles]

Comment: okay, thanks—i will definitely try this! I was trying to figure out on my own how I could apply the zero tracking into this equation—i was trying to add some space after the tracked pair, but it wasn't working.

Comment: @Brendan The regular expression you're referring to, "if [something] is followed by [something else] then [style]" is called "Positive Lookahead". Its complement is "negative lookahead" "if [thing] is *not* followed by [other thing] then..." GREP also has positive and negative look-behind. They are very useful for esoteric GREP styles.

Comment: @VirginiaNorey, see Alan's answer...his should serve you better.

Answer (score 2):

I should have been more explicit in my original answer on this topic. The way you make this work is by using GREP's "Positive Lookahead". Here's an expression that applies a character style to a letter that is followed by an ogonek: `[\l\u](?=˛)` In English that means "apply the style to any single upper or lowercase letter that comes immediately before an ogonek, but not to the ogonek itself.

You would have to experiment with the exact negative tracking value for the particular typeface you were using. In my case it was -400 using Myriad Pro at 12 pt.

Comment: Thanks...my knowledge of regular expressions is pretty limited :)